# How do I randomly spawn enemy elsewhere after collision in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

for some reason when I collide with the enemy it randomly spawns elsewhere which is all fine but when I un-collide the enemy goes back to its original position
here is the full code down below. If you run this code see what happens. Im looking for the red block to spawn in a random other location when the blue box collides with it.

```py
import pygame
import random

# places where enemies can spawn (2 to make it simple at first)
enemy_locations = [100, 200]


pygame.init()
# clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# frames per second
fps = 30

# colors
background_color = (255, 255, 255)
player_color = (0, 0, 255)
enemy_color = (255, 0, 0)

# width and height of screen
width = 1000
height = 800

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# x, y coordinates player
player_x = 300
player_y = 300

# ememy x, y coordinates
enemy_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
enemy_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)

# new x, y coordinates for enemy player
new_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
new_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)

# draw player
def draw():
    enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, 25, 25)
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, 25, 25)

    if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
        enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, (new_x, new_y, 25, 25))
    else:
        enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, enemy_rect)

    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player_rect)

# pygame loop (always include)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # controls for player object
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_x -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_x += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_y -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_y += 10

    draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(background_color)
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: Here  when you use `new_x = random.choice()`  you give it as an argument a list with only 2 values, so there are only 4 possible x, y combinations where an enemy can potentially spawn. Instead use `new_x = random.randint(0, width)` and `new_y = random.randint(0, height)`. This would result in a random location anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said you either need to add more "locations" to the list or better, use `random.randint()`, and also enemy's coordinates does not "get random"(or updated in any way) after every collision, but only once when you initialize them.
I added new function `get_new_coord()` which will return the random number(I use these limits so the enemy won't go off the screen), which gets called once for every coordinate after each collision.
Also I moved `player_rect` and `enemy_rect` outside of the loop, and now `draw()` returns `enemy_rect` so it can stay updated if collision occurs.

This is a quick fix to your code, you should consider using Classes. And of course if you want to do so, I could help you with transforming the code.

```
import pygame
import random

# places where enemies can spawn (2 to make it simple at first)
enemy_locations = [100, 200]


pygame.init()
# clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# frames per second
fps = 30

# colors
background_color = (255, 255, 255)
player_color = (0, 0, 255)
enemy_color = (255, 0, 0)

# width and height of screen
width = 1000
height = 800

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# x, y coordinates player
player_x = 300
player_y = 300

# ememy x, y coordinates
enemy_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
enemy_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)

# new x, y coordinates for enemy player
new_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
new_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)

def get_new_coord():
    return random.randint(0, 800-25)

# draw player
def draw(player_rect, enemy_rect):

    screen.fill(background_color)

    if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
        enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(get_new_coord(), get_new_coord(), 25, 25)
        enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, enemy_rect)
    else:
        enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, enemy_rect)

    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player_rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    return enemy_rect


# pygame loop (always include)
running = True
enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, 25, 25)
player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, 25, 25)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # controls for player object
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_rect.x -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_rect.x += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_rect.y -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += 10

    enemy_rect = draw(player_rect, enemy_rect)

    clock.tick(fps)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `draw` method explicitly states to draw enemy rect either in the initial point or in some ONE random point. The random point is selected only once - during the start of an application. You should set the random point every time there is a collision in a `draw` method, e.g.

```
if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
    enemy_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
    enemy_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new random enemy position when the player collides with the enemy

```py
if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
    enemy_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
    enemy_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)
```

Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt), to interpreted the variables `enemy_x` and `enemy_y` as global. With the statement `global` it is possible to write to variables in the global namespace within a function:

```py
global enemy_x, enemy_y
```

Function `draw`:

```py
def draw():
    global enemy_x, enemy_y

    enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, 25, 25)
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, 25, 25)

    if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
        enemy_x = random.choice(enemy_locations)
        enemy_y = random.choice(enemy_locations)
        
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, enemy_rect)
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player_rect)
```